# How to connect a node docker container with postgres docker container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a CRUD app working on node, on my local machine. It is running on node, with postgres as the database, using knex.js as a query builder, etc.

I have created a docker file, and a docker-compose file, and the containers start, but the node container can't reach the postgres container. I suspect it has to do with the enviornment variables but I am not sure. here is my docker file:

```
FROM node:12
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

ENV PORT=8080
EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USER: app
      POSTGRES_DB: db

  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - "postgres"
    links:
      - "postgres"
    environment:
      DB_PASSWORD: 'password'
      DB_USER: 'app'
      DB_NAME: 'db'
      DB_HOST: 'postgres'
      PORT: 8080
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    command: npm start
```

also, here is the `knex.js` file on root that handles the db connections based on the environment:

```
// Update with your config settings.

module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: 'postgres://localhost/db'
  },
  test: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: 'postgres://localhost/test-db'
  }
};
```

additionally when I check the hosts file on the node app inside the docker i don't see anything mentioning the link to postgres container. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your node application is not connecting is because it is trying to connect to itself as you are referencing `localhost`. Your database is in a second container which is not local so you need to reference it by service name which would be `postgres`.

So assuming your application is handling authentication another way, your config would be something like this:

```
// Update with your config settings.

module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: 'postgres://postgres/db'
  },
  test: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: 'postgres://postgres/test-db'
  }
};
```

If you can, you should use the environment variables you assigned to the `app` container.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was figuring, I was not sure how I should update the connection file though. I will try your suggested edits. Assuming this works, I can then theoretically run migrations from the node container and and it should migrate/seed the database as it normally would?

Comment: It looks like your Dockerfile will copy the entire source into the image so just ensure you run `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose down; docker-compose up -d` which should update the new file. You can verify by `docker-compose exec app cat /path/to/knex.js` to see if it has the edits. Yes, as long as you have successfully established the connection your migrations should work. That said, I don't see you passing in any credentials anywhere into the connection string so that may need to be fixed first.

Comment: I did attempt to try to pass the credentials from the connection string, but i believe the format was wrong as I was getting some strange errors. I am looking for docs to show me what the string should be formatted like, if I don't find it soon enough, would you be so kind as to tell me what the proper format is? I assume I need to pass the credentials from the `docker-compose` file?

Comment: I did end up getting it to work, `connection: 'postgres://app:password@postgres/db'`

now i need to figure out how to add the second test database in my docker-compose

Comment: Good. I don't think you can create a second db with the out of the box entrypoint though. You may need to either manually create it or modify the entrypoint (E.g., https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/0a66d53fface5ccc8274f99712ba2f382a1caf42/12/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh).

Comment: I learned that the hard way, my idea is now to just have two separate containers one for development, and one for tests, as I have two db's for said purposes on my local, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Docker-compose creates an internal network shared by the different containers it launches.
Since `app` and `postgres` are 2 separate containers, they are considered as 2 hosts. This causes app to look for postgres on the same container when you point it at `localhost` instead of the postgres container.

You can solve this by just changing `localhost` with `postgres` in your `knex.js` file.